# Strategies for serializing an object for auditing/logging purpose in .NET?

Tags: .net, xml, logging, serialization

Let's say I have an application that processes messages.  Messages are just objects in this case that implements *IMessage* interface which is just a marker.

In this app, if a message fails to process, then I want to log it, first of all for auditing and troubleshooting purposes.  Secondly I might want to use it for re-processing.

Ideally, I want the message to be serialized into a format that is human-readable.  The first candidate is XML although there are others like JSON.  If I were to serialize the messages as XML, I want to know whether the message object is XML-serializable.  One way is to reflect on the type and to see if it has a parameter-less constructor and the other is to require *IXmlSerializable* interface.  I'm not too happy with either of these approaches.  There is a third option which is to try to serialize it and catch exceptions.  This doesn't really help - I want to, in some way, stipulate that *IMessage* (or a derived type) should be xml-serializable.

The reflection route has obvious disadvantages such as security, performance, etc.
*IXmlSerializable* route locks down my messages to one format, when in the future, I might want to change the serialization format to be JSON.  The other thing is even the simplest objects now must implement *ReadXml* and *WriteXml* methods.

Is there a route that involves the least amount of work that lets me serialize an arbitrary object (as long as it implements the marker interface) into XML but not lock future messages into XML?

Comment: Hard to see how this could be a real problem.  If not through design, you'll surely find out that a class isn't serializable when you debug.

Comment: A parameterless constructor is necessary for Xml Serialization but it is not sufficient to guarantee the successful serialization of "an arbitrary object".  e.g. your object could contain fields that cannot be serialized such as IDictionary.

Comment: Exactly Tuzo - I need something more than that.  Something like IXmlSerializable that says this object is intended for Xml Serialization but that does not force me to implement ReadXml/WriteXml.

Comment: Hans - Not sure what you mean.  At runtime, IMessage could be anything.  Like I said, it's just a marker interface.  An implementation could be anything, written by anyone.

Comment: Very good point Tuzo. Whatever method you take you're going to have to ensure the object you're using in the message are themselvese serializable. Here's my `SerializableDictionary` if you need it :-) http://ccutilities.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/47096#721197

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a MessageBase that all your message objects derive from that contains a parameterless constructor. Then use `MessageBase` rather than `IMessage`.

Curious though, if you design the messages and have the intention for them to all be serializable why do you need to check?

Here's a generic object extension I use a lot:

```
/// <summary>        
/// Converts an object to a serialized xml string       
/// </summary>
/// <param name="o">The <see cref="object"/> to serialize</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string ToXml(this object o)
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(o.GetType());

    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(streamWriter, o);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            memoryStream.Flush();
            memoryStream.Position = 0;

            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
            {
                return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Implement it on your MessageBase and you're golden. No locking in to anything.

Comment: Now the code must test against MessageBase to serialize, which kind of defeats the purpose of having IMessage in the first place.

Comment: By the way, I use StringWriter/StringBuilder for xml serialization.  Not sure what, if there is any, the differences are.

Comment: Well yes. Personally an interface with no methods defeats the purpose for me. It doesn't indicate that you can actually *DO* anything specific with the object which is what you are trying to do. Represent that an object both contains the necessary methods for serialization and has been designed with proper objects that also can be serialized.

Answer (score 1):

So the requirement is to serialize an arbitrary object (as long as it
implements the marker interface) into human readable format (possibly
XML) in the easiest possible manner.

As mentioned in [Is It Serializable?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jaredpar/is-it-serializable) determining if an object is serializable is hard.

I can think of only 2 ways to meet the requirements:

1. Add a Serialize method to the IMessage interface and force classes
   to implement their own human readable format.
2. Have your application interface be exposed as a service that
   accepts a human readable format.  e.g. a WCF service that accepts a
   human readable message (XML) that you can log.

Option 1 may be good for auditing but not so much for reprocessing. Also there are still some edge cases that might cause problems.

If this is an existing application then those are probably not viable options.  If that is the case then maybe look at something like [Json.NET](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=json) to try to serialize on a best effort basis.